# Does MailEnable Standart Edition support APIs?

Tags: email

It seems it doesn't support APIs, cannot create user, cannot change password, etc. forum.mailenable.com keeps the answer as secret.

```
  If oLogin.getLogin() Then

          oLogin.Password = newpass              
          ChangeResult = oLogin.EditLogin(oLogin.UserName, oLogin.Status, oLogin.Password, oLogin.Account, oLogin.Description, 0, 0, 0, oLogin.Rights)

   End If
```

**ChangeResult** may contain 1 (success) but the result might not be OK in real; that's what my problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Standard Edition does not support API's.  Professional and higher versions support. I've installed Pro, when the trial ends it becomes Standard and then won't support APIs anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This API gudie shows the commands you are able to use [PDF for API](http://mailenable.org/developers/MailEnable%20API%20Guide.pdf)

Comment: People informs that API returns the code 1 "success" but nothing happens, no new user, no password change... I can't decide it's my or ME's problem.